# Grouped mean across list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe

From the `tapply` function I am obtaining a list of data frames, each of them with columns `A=c(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)` and `B=c(y_1, y_2, ..., y_n)` where `x_i, y_i` are always numeric.

What is important is to know that `A` is *always* the same for each data frame, while `B` varies.

I want to get the average `y_i` for each `x_i` in all these dataframes. The obvious way to do it is to join them:

```
joined <- bind_rows(list_of_dfs)
aggregate(joined$B, list(joined$A), mean)
```

But joining is quite costly and makes the program rather slow. The size of the data I handle makes efficiency important.  How could I perform the aggregation with the mean function without joining the data frames?

Reproducible example:

```
A = 1:20
X = rnorm(20)
Y = rnorm(20)
Z = rnorm(20)

# Note that only B differs across dfs
df1 <- data.frame(A=A, B=X)
df2 <- data.frame(A=A, B=Y)
df3 <- data.frame(A=A, B=Z)

list_of_dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)

# Obvious solution involves joining:

joined <- bind_rows(list_of_dfs)
# Compute mean grouped by A
aggregate(joined$B, list(joined$A), mean)
```

Comment: If you don't need to join, then use `Reduce("+", lapply(list_of_dfs, "[[", 'B'))/length(list_of_dfs)`

Comment: But you are taking the average of `B` without grouping with respect to `A`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You mentioned 'A' is the same.  Once you get the mean, then if there are more than one unique values of 'A' in the data, use `aggregate` on that Reduced data with 'A' from a single dataset

Comment: Across columns. Meaning that `df1, df2, df3` have the same `A` column.

Comment: Yes, I meant  `aggregate(rowSums(sapply(list_of_dfs, "[[", "B")), list(list_of_dfs[[1]]$A), mean)`

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I missunderstood. This works like a charm and gives exactly the same output as the obvious solution in my reproducible example. Care to make this an answer instead of a comment? Perhaps provide a bit more detail on why the mean is being computed with grouping included, even without using the aggregate function.

Comment: my assumption with first solution was that, each element in 'A' is unique.  In second solution I used `aggregate` assumiing that there are duplicates for 'A' in a single data and you want to summarise.  As these are made up examples, I was not sure which way you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in the `A` column are unique in the single dataset and this column is replicated in each of the datasets in the `list`, an easier option is to extract (`[[`) only the column 'B' from the `list`, get the elementwise sum (`+`) with `Reduce` and divide by the `length` of the `list` to get the elementwise mean

```
out1 <- data.frame(A = list_of_dfs[[1]]$A, B = Reduce("+",
         lapply(list_of_dfs, "[[", 'B'))/length(list_of_dfs))
```

---

In case if there are `NA` elements, the above method may return `NA` for that element, so, we may use `rowMeans` instead which also can remove the `NA`s with `na.rm` argument

```
out2 <- data.frame(A = list_of_dfs[[1]]$A, 
     B = rowMeans(sapply(list_of_dfs, "[[", "B"), na.rm = TRUE))
```

-checking

```
> all.equal(out1, out2)
[1] TRUE
```